# Jenkins Artifactory Plugin multi-project release

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory

I have configured jenkins and the artifactory plugin to work and do the release for single project.

I recently created a multi-project, and im not sure how to release so that all dependant projects have the version incremented.

So for instance Project A -> Project B - > Project C

If i release project C from jenkins will this cause an increment in versions for all projects, i really cant be messing around with releases... so have not tested this.

Thanks

Comment: cant do this. unless its multi module project in maven then it can work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maven multi module project.

If the projects are not multi module than i will need update each one individually.